# How To Setup iOS App to Have Notify Button on App Store Pre-Launch

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Some iOS apps that have not yet launched on the iOS app store now (Super Mario) have the ability for users to click a button on the app store listing to be notified when the app becomes available. How is this done?  This will obviously impact a large number of apps/developers.  If this is not yet possible for general release apps from the general developer community, only for apps that have specially arranged it with Apple, please update answers to this question when/if this becomes generally available, which seems likely.

Please do not downvote this question as 'off topic' given that the answer to this will *obviously* be important to a lot of iOS developers who turn to SO for answers (like I just did).

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although it may be of interest to programmers, it is *not about programming*

Comment: If you look at the top 10 SO questions of ALL TIME by votes, you with notice the FOUR of them do not actually involve questions that are explicitly about programming, but about how to use tools that are critical to programmers (eg Git).  In general, questions on SO that address topics of broad importance to programmers regarding how to deal with their code are much more valuable and widely used here than questions about a little code snipped that applies to almost no one.  If you disagree, I believe that you, and some others here, are missing the forest for the trees/rules.

Comment: Git is a tool that is used by programmers and is therefore on-topic as described in the help centre (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If you hover over the `app-store` tag you will see that your question is not on-topic for that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a feature part of the Apple Developer Program.